# Como hicieron para que les mostrara todos los registros (282) de una base de datos (reservas) en full calendar? los traigo pero aparecen problemas

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Esta es una mezcla de javascript con php
señores, necesito ayuda urgente por favor!!!!
si lo han aplicado a su proyecto!!.

```
        <?php foreach($rs_coti as $fila): 
        nombre: '<?php echo $fila['nombre']; ?>',
                telefono: '<?php echo $fila['telefono']; ?>',
                email: '<?php echo $fila['email']; ?>',
                rut: '<?php echo $fila['rut']; ?>',
                checkin: '<?php echo $checkin; ?>',
                checkout: '<?php echo $checkout; ?>',
                color: '<?php echo $fila['color']; ?>',
                comentario: '<?php echo $fila['comentario']; ?>',
                cod_cotiz: '<?php echo $fila['cod_cotiz']; ?>',
                valor: '<?php echo $fila['valor']; ?>',
                pagado: '<?php echo $fila['pagado']; ?>',


            },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es generar código JAVASCRIPT desde php, lo puedes hacer solo tienes que estar atento a aperturas y cierres de los pares de  etiquetas `<?php` `?>` , también puedes usar `<?= ?>` que reemplaza a  `<?php echo 'texto' ?>`.

El código quedaría así:

```php
    <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <?php
    $rs_coti = [ [ "nombre"=>" EL NOMBRE" ] ];
    ?>
    <script>
        var datos = [  // js
    <?php  foreach($rs_coti as $fila):  //php ?>            
                {  
                   'nombre': '<?=$fila['nombre']; ?>',  //js y php
                },
    <?php  endforeach; // php ?>
        ]; // js
        console.log(datos); //js
    </script>
    </html>
```

El resultado sera este :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
<script>
 var datos = [
   
   {
        'nombre': ' EL NOMBRE',
   },
    ];
    console.log(datos);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: bro me puedes dejar tu whatsapp o facebook porque ahi no agregue el codigo completo